# "%2F" will be changed into "/" when "like"

Tags: javascript, facebook-like

When "like" the url written below, a problem occurs.

http://example.com/aaa/bbb/ccc/xxx%2Fxxx/

The link url in "Edit Profile > Activities and Interests > Other Pages You Like" is

.../aaa/bbb/ccc/xxx%2Fxxx/

But the link url in a user wall is

.../aaa/bbb/ccc/xxx/xxx/

What should I do for using the right link also in a user wall?

Javascript source code:

```
function getFacebookUrl() {
    var thisPath = location.pathname;
    var fbUrl;
    var host = location.host;
    var regex = new RegExp("\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/");

    if (thisPath.match(regex)) {
        thisPath = "/" + RegExp.$1 + "/" + RegExp.$2 + "/" + RegExp.$3 + "/" + encodeURIComponent(RegExp.$4) + "/";
    }

    fbUrl = location.protocol + "//" + host + thisPath;
    return encodeURIComponent(fbUrl);
}

var url = getFacebookUrl();

document.write('<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=' + url + '&amp;send=false&amp;layout=box_count&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=true&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=65" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:74px; height:65px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>');
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
var url = unescape('http://example.com/aaa/bbb/ccc/xxx%2Fxxx/');
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.
But it was the same result.

Comment: @YujiTamai My answer replaces the "%2F" with "/", thus creating a "correct" url. Isnt that what you wanted? Did tou want the opposite?

Comment: The parameter is divided by "/". And the 4th parameter must be a value of "xxx/xxx". It progressed for a while. It seems to be the problem of the value of "og:url."

Comment: It succeeded, when "xxx%2Fxxx" of "og:url" was encoded. Successful "og:url" is "<meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com/aaa/bbb/ccc/xxx%252Fxxx/" />
"